# Is it possible to split text over two lines in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, formatting

Firstly, sorry if the title is not very accurate, I couldn't think of a better way to describe this problem.

I am working on a CV and would like use a format similar to a pdf that was produced via a job site whilst having control of the content myself. On the first line they have a name at the top left in bold font Arial-BoldMT 26.5 then on the top right they have two lines in smaller text ArialMT 7.5 that take up around the same amount of height.

Is it possible to replicate this in MS Word?

[image: Here is an image of what I mean:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with the [text box](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-text-box-HP005238164.aspx).

So, keep your name on the left as you already have, then draw a text box (which can be found under insert in the ribbon) in the desired size/position and type inside.

The text box content can have it's own style/font/colour/size etc.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible.

One way is by using a table.

At the top of the page client `Insert` - `Table` and choose a `2 x 1` table.

You can then set the properties of each cell individually, just play with the fonts and sizes until you find the ones you want and then remove the border.

Comment: I would argue it's not the 'easiest', however, it's a great suggestion for another approach.

Comment: I personally feel it is the easiest but the term easiest is very personal. Whats easiest for me is difficult for someone else and a waste of time for someone else.
Reworded my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

You could contain the text on the right in a text box

[image: Screen cap of text alignment for OP]

This will allow you to position it however you want without touching the properties of your title